# Conveying "on board" (involved in a project or organization or working for a company)

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

The idiom "on board" may be used to imply involvement in a project or organization, or working for a company. E.g.

> Welcome to the team. **It’s great/nice/good to have you on board**.

What are some common ways to convey its meaning in this context other than

> Bienvenue dans l'équipe. **C'est super de vous avoir avec nous**.

I think the literal translation **à bord** is not idiomatic (in this context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Bienvenue à bord*

is not completely unidiomatic. It seems to me that we hear it more and more, perhaps under some influence of English.

Alternatively, you can move l'*équipe*:

> Bienvenue. C'est une bonne nouvelle de vous avoir dans l'équipe.

> Bienvenue. C'est super de t'avoir dans l'équipe.

Keeping the boat metaphor:

> Bienvenue dans l'équipe. C'est super que tu sois embarqué avec nous sur ce projet.

Answer (score 2):

Effectivement, certains pourraient penser à "Bienvenue à bord", mais ça ne marche pas trop dans ce contexte.

Je dirai plutôt :

> Bienvenue dans l'équipe. C'est super de vous avoir **parmi** nous.

Comment: Merci. À bord n'a pas ce sens idiomatic, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: Oui et non, elle l'est plutôt dans l'expression "Bienvenue à bord !". Mais sans le bienvenue, l'expression n'a plus de sens.